# How to fix wrong vagrant box name for homestead

Tags: php, vagrant, laravel-5.1, homestead

I installed homestead box manually but I made a mistake in box name during installation. Instead of `laravel/homestead` I gave only `homestead` Now my `vagrant box list` gives

`homestead (virtualbox, 0)`

So I tried renaming `homestead` folder name in  `~/vagrant.d/boxes`. But `/` is not allowed due to that I tried to put homestead folder inside a folder `laravel` but then `vagrant` not detecting the box.

Is there any solution to rename my box to `laravel/homestead` without adding the box again. ? I don't have that box and vagrant box super slow **20Kbps** in my region.

Due to this wrong name homestead project is not detecting the box so trying to download it again.

My sys config is MacbookAir.

Comment: Interesting! Seems related to https://superuser.com/questions/350657/can-i-rename-a-vagrant-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution

**Slow solution**

Repacking a box then adding `package.box` with correct name is another way

`vagrant box repackage homestead virtualbox 0` --> To make a package from installed box

And then add this package with correct name

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead ./package.box`

**Fast method**

After adding the correct box name I checked `boxes` folder to know how they implemented the `/` is box name

Got to `boxes` folder, By default it would be  `~/.vagrant.d/boxes`

Then rename the folder like this

`mv homestead laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead`

To conclude `-VAGRANTSLASH-` is used to add `/` in the box name